# One input break in 3 variables

Tags: java, input

i know this is a silly question but What i want to do is to input 1 line and break it into 3 variables. what i want to input is time the hour minute and second "10:30:40" and i want it to store into variable a b c. a = hour b = minute c = seconds

public class Bituka {

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Biek littlepig = new Biek();

    String x = null;
    String y = null;
    String z = null;

    System.out.println("Enter Time");
    x = br.readLine();
    y = br.readLine();
    z = br.readLine();

    int a = Integer.parseInt(x);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(y);
    int c = Integer.parseInt(z);

    littlepig.setTime(a,b,c);



    System.out.println(littlepig.toMilitary());



}
```

}

Comment: Break "it" into three variables? What is "it" referring to? What,exactly, do you want to break into three variables?

Comment: @Houseman what i want to input is time 10:30:40 and I want to store the hour minute and second to a b c variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you input the time, take it as a string and then split the string: (The input is "hour:minute:second")

```
System.out.println("Enter Time");
String timeString = br.readLine();
String[] timeArray = timeString.split(":"); //Splits the string with regex ":"

int hour = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[0]);
int minute = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[1]);
int second = Integer.parseInt(timeArray[2]);
```

And set the time with `hour`, `minute`, and `second`.

Comment: Cool code bro i never thought there was a split method. Where can i see all available methods in java?

Comment: Everything you need is in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)